# CORBA server on JVM 1.2 and client on 1.3

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have a corba server compiled and running on **JVM 1.2**. I am using the java IDL to compile the IDL file and generate the required stubs and skeletons and using a NameService to start the server. I am able to connect to the server if running the client on the same system, but if i try running the client on a different machine on **JVM 1.3** I am not able to connect to the server.
 However I am able to run thhis on two different machines both on **JVM 1.2**, these are the commands i am using
On the server

`tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 2000

java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 2000  -ORBInitialHost myhost`

On the client machine
`java HelloClient -ORBInitialPort 2000  -ORBInitialHost myhost`


But I am getting the following error at the client side. I referred to the example on this site http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/idl/GShome.html

Error stacktrace

`ERROR : org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   minor code: 1398079490  completed: No
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   minor code: 1398079490  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.iiop.IIOPConnection.writeLock(IIOPConnection.java:956)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.iiop.IIOPConnection.send(IIOPConnection.java:1017)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.invoke(IIOPOutputStream.java:71)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.iiop.ClientRequestImpl.invoke(ClientRequestImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.corba.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:153)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.corba.InitialNamingClient.resolve(InitialNamingClient.java:195)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.corba.InitialNamingClient.cachedInitialReferences(InitialNamingClient.java:260)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.corba.InitialNamingClient.resolve_initial_references(InitialNamingClient.java:183)
        at com.sun.corba.se.internal.corba.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1465)
        at HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:17)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that Java *1.5* is two years into end-of-life, 1.3 is nearly five years, and 1.2 I don't know how far, I *strongly* suggest you run both client and server on something current, i.e. 1.6 or 1.7 if you're an early adopter, which clearly you aren't ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that JVM1.2 has reached its EOL, but i am developing an interface for a client whose existing application was developed on JVM 1.2. So I am deploying my application on JVM 1.6 and the client's existing application on 1.2 needs to communicate with 1.6. I could have used RMI, but the requirement is to make my application a generic interface, that is the reason I am using corba. There are other corba libs like jacORB, but this is supported only for java 1.4 and higher. So I was just wondering if its possible to communicate from java 1.2/1.3 to 1.6 using corba

Comment: @Rakesh it should be possible but you are dealing with just about the most extreme case of inter-JVM interoperability there is. It would be well worth trying your client's application on 1.6. They are going to have to migrate some time, and they should have done it years ago.

Comment: the thing is my client doesn't want to migrate to higher JVM since they have to re-design their existing application. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to convince my client to migrate to current version of JVM

Comment: @Ralesh All your client has to do is *test* it on a current JVM. If it works, they are done. If it doesn't, which is extremely unlikely, they have a minor debugging exercise. Certainly no redesign is necessary.